# Can't start MAMP servers

Tags: server, mamp

i am unable to start servers, the 'start servers'-icon flashes green for a second and nothing happens. This is what i get in the apache_error log:

```
[Mon Dec 26 03:36:16 2016] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Mon Dec 26 03:36:17 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Dec 26 03:36:17 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Dec 26 03:36:18 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2e mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/7.0.9 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 26 03:36:18 2016] [notice] Server built: May  6 2016 10:19:53
[Mon Dec 26 03:36:18 2016] [crit] (22)Invalid argument: Parent: Failed to create the child process.
[Mon Dec 26 03:36:18 2016] [crit] (OS 6)Invalid reference.  : master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

Answer (score 6):

I  had the same problem on Windows 10 and disabling Perl worked for me:

C:\MAMP\conf\apache\httpd.conf
...

## LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so

...

I hope this helps.